# Multithreading and files

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want a general utility class to be able to write to files in a specific folder. If I want to make it concurrent (so, for example, if an image is being written in chunks, it gets written in order and not at random since it's in different threads), could I have a File object with the path to the folder itself but no specific file (let's call it folder), and call the following?

```
    synchronized(folder){
        //Open the output stream to the specific file needed and handle it
    }
```

Comment: It would have to be the same instance of `File`. You could generate a "lock object" for a `String` path and keep it in a `Map` maybe

Comment: So I couldn't lock the folder File object and would have to do each separate file?

Comment: You "could" lock on a `File` object, but it would have to be the same instance of `File` each time (for each thread). I'd create a `Map<String, Object>` which you could use the `File#getPath` or similar method (`getCanonicalFile` might be better) to store references to the physical "lock" object

Comment: This question makes no sense.  If the image is _"being written in chunks... in different threads"_ the threads have to cooperate to ensure the chunks are created in the proper order.  Please clarify what your are trying to achieve.  This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)